# Which file is responsible for off the canvas menu in mobile view in rwd theme?

Tags: magento-1.9

Where does off the canvas menu comes from in Magento 1.9.2? Which file is responsible for it? How can I make off the canvas menu default in desktop view?

Answer (score 0):

go to this path file app/design/frontend/your-theme/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml

hope you can got your answer, you can customize this file if you use your own theme, or you can edit existing theme